# Is DROP CONSTRAINT of default values a size of data operation

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table with some values in it and I 
`ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD [column_name] BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [default_constraint] DEFAULT (1)`. This won't be a size of data operation as the default value will be stored once and referenced in each existing row in the new column.

But what if I decide later to drop the `[default_constraint]`? Will that become a size of data operation?

Comment: "size of data" isn't a phrase I recognize. If you look at [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224807(v=sql.80).aspx) under the "How does it do that?" section, are you trying to differentiate between the three ways that an `ALTER TABLE` might need to act?

Comment: By size of data I meant will the server walk trough every row and update it with the default value.

Answer (score 0):

> `ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD [column_name] BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [default_constraint] DEFAULT (1)`. This won't be a size of data operation as the default value will be stored once and referenced in each existing row in the new column.

This is incorrect. SQL Server has to alter every existing row and physically store a copy of the default value in every row. When a table has a default constraint (after any operation which adds it), the constraint is used *only* at `INSERT` time - it doesn't treat the defaulted value differently or try to optimize storage by only storing one instance of the value across the whole table.

Conversely, just dropping the constraint is a metadata-only operation, since it doesn't alter the existing values that are already stored in the rows.